# Two variables limit / differentiable function

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

How do I show that the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}\cos(y)$$
does not exist?

I have to prove that the function
$$f(x,y)=x^{1/3}\cos(y)$$
is not differentiable in $(0,0)$, so I calculated (using limit):
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$$
And now I'm trying to show that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$, but I can't answer my question (the limit above).

Comment: Bevor discussing continuity or differentiability of $f $, you should tell  how $f $  is defined at (0,0) !

Comment: That's the function...

Comment: @mvfs314 $f(x,y)=x^{1/3}\cos y\implies f(0,0)=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $f(x,0)=x^{1/3}.$ Thus

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{1/3}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} x^{-2/3}.$$ Are you able to show that this limit doesn't exist?

Comment: Oh! My mistake! Thanks.